# How to update row field if new value is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create prepared statement where function will receive bunch of fields is Option. if field is Some then I want to update that field. if it is None then I don't want to update that field without setting it to null in Database. How can I achive this?

something like this:-

```sql
UPDATE animal SET
  name = newval IF newval IS NOT NULL,
  age = newval2 IF newval2 IS NOT NULL,
  type = newval3 IF newval3 IS NOT NULL,
  color = newval4 IF newval4 IS NOT NULL,
 ...
```

Also some fields are large blobs of 1 to 3 GBs so I don't think putting entire blob two times in prepared statement is good idea

Comment: Not `IF` but `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
UPDATE x SET a = IFNULL(na, a), b = IFNULL(nb, b), ...
```

> It's generally better to compose your query carefully and omit any "non-updating" fields from it. Making a query with a bunch of useless junk in it wastes the database server's time.

Comment: Will it write old value again in database or database smartly does not write old value again ?

Comment: It just uses `na` unless it's `NULL`, in which case the old value is reassigned. It's inefficient, but effective.